# @AfterReturning failed to intercept the method invoking by aspectJ

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Here is a part of spring xml file:

```
    <!-- aop config -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean id="fileService" class="com.test.file.FileService" />
<bean id="throughputManager" class="com.test.mbean.ThroughputManager" />
```

following with the java code:

```
public class FileService {
public long read(Object obj,String id) throws Exception {
    return 0L;
    }

public long write(Object obj,String id) throws Exception {
    return 0L;
    }
}


@Aspect
public class ThroughputManager {

public static long TOTAL_READ_THROUGHPUT;
public static long TOTAL_WRITE_THROUGHPUT;

@AfterReturning(
        pointcut="execution(* com.test.file.FileService.read(..))",
        returning="size"
        )
public void calculateReadThroughput(long size) throws IOException{
    TOTAL_READ_THROUGHPUT+=size;
}

@AfterReturning(
        pointcut="execution(* com.test.file.FileService.write(..))",
        returning="size"
        )
public void calculateWriteThroughput(long size) throws IOException{
    TOTAL_WRITE_THROUGHPUT+=size;
}
}
```

When I debug the program and call the `read` and `write` method, the two methods in the `ThroughputManager` were not invoked. I tried to find the reason but it seems everything about the code are fine. Could anyone help to find out what's wrong with this aop invoking?Thx.

Comment: Post the code where you are actually testing this. My guess is you aren't testing the instance configured in spring but are constructing a new instance and use that for testing.

Comment: @Deepak2221 No exception. I know if an exception is thrown, the invoke would fail. But I was testing within a non-exception situation. So.. still have no clue.

Comment: @M.Deinum Mmm.. actually, I was testing within the jetty environment. The whole program is a web application with jetty as the server container. The spring instance was substantiated by jetty itself. Could it account for the failure?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. Although I registered `FileService` as a bean in spring configuration xml, I didn't call `read` and `write` methods through the `FileService` bean--the instance from `getBeans` method. Instead, I just `new` a `FileService` instance and invoke the two methods. What a blunder...